# Is csrf enough for security when posting data to server via axios?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I use Laravel for a project. It is not a vue SPA, so no route used at all. The register, login and some other form inputs and outputs are made with modals using vue. For posting the form vars axios is used. For server side authentication laravels standard auth is used. But here is no other authentication like jwt. Should I use other auth types or would csrf be enough? Are there other suggestions?

Comment: JWT is used in much the same way as  OAuth or SAML etc. for authenticating things like API requests.  Its not an alternative for csrf which serves a different purpose.  When using the same server for both your front and backend what Laravel has by default should be enough.  That is not to say that there is not other things you can do to make authentication more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually for web routes csrf token is enough secure or it has been so far. And it does:

1. Check if the request is a reading request (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS).
2. If so, skip the check. Match the token from the _token input or from the headers.
3. Add a cookie with the token to each request.

If you are using `api` routes then you can chose from Laravel [passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport) which you can setup oAuth2 or you could build your own custom auth middleware using jwt tokens.